# Apply Picture Styles using Macro in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to apply Picture Styles to a picture added using Macro in VBA Excel, but I am unable to find a way. I have tried using Record Macro but it did'nt helped me. So is it possible to apply Picture Styles using Macro in VBA Excel?

Answer (score 1):

You can use define the style of your shape (actually a picture is implemented as a shape) with the properties of the the [Shape Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/shape-object-excel).

For example you can define

```
myShape.ShapeStyle
myShape.Shadow
myShape.Glow.Color
myShape.Glow.Radius
```

and some more. See the [Shape Object documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/shape-object-excel) for more properties.

Comment: @Peh  thanks for reply I have tried but still not able to add Picture Style.

Comment: @Shitalb What do you mean by "picture style"? The "Quick Styles", the "Picture Effects"? As far as I know you cannot access the presets in VBA you need to add all the things like shadow and glow individually.

Comment: @PEH There is Format menu under Picture Tools, when we add Picture. And from Format Menu I want to apply Picture Styles.

Comment: @Shitalb as I said before you cannot use the presets form that menu in VBA you will need to adjust every single effect on the shape/picture.